# wp_schedule_event is registered but function isn't running

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I'm trying to run a function on an hourly basis with wp_schedule_event. I'm using the following code:

```
/* Add FB Sync schedule */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cp_fb_schedule');

// Scheduled Action Hook
function cp_fb_scheduled_sync( ) {
//      run the function
}

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function cp_fb_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'cp_fb_schedule' );

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('cp_fb_scheduled_sync');
}
```

I have checked with wp_next_scheduled and can see that the event is scheduled and the next one is due an hour after the last. So that appears to be working. 
The function I am trying to run works fine when I call it directly within a page (I've omitted the code here just so it's easier to read). It just doesn't run on schedule.

Can anyone work out what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed.

Comment: Hi @Drupalizeme, I've tried visiting the website myself and it hasn't run the function. I've just edited the function to make it a simple wp_mail to make sure it wasn't overcomplication with the function itself.

This still doesn't work as scheduled. The wp_schedule_event code is a sub-folder of a plugin, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored the code and tested so this should put you in the right direction!
But what I changed? I add the **action hook** `cp_fb_scheduled_sync` and set it to call it `hourly` this only needs to run one time and the WP knows the intervals.

```
/* Add FB Sync schedule */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cp_fb_schedule');

// Scheduled Action Hook
function cp_fb_scheduled_sync_function( ) {
//      run the function
}

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function cp_fb_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync' );
    }
}
add_action( 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync', 'cp_fb_scheduled_sync_function' );

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('cp_fb_scheduled_sync');
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that did it! I guess it was my action hook that was messed up. Thanks so much